# Inverse Fourier transform of a function generated from a compactly supported function

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces, harmonic-analysis, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Suppose $u$ belongs to a Sobolev space $H^s$ ($s\ge 0$).  Assume $u$ has compact support.  Does $f$ which is defined by $f=\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\hat{u}(\xi^2))$ have also compact support? Or more generally, $f=\mathcal{F}^{-1}(p(\xi)\hat{u}(\xi^2))$ where $p(\xi)$ is polynomial or rational.

Comment: So in other words, you mean to ask if $u$ is compactly supported, then is the function $f$ defined by the following also compactly supported? $$ f(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{i\xi x}\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-it\xi^2} u(t)\,dt\,d\xi$$

Comment: No, why do you think so, and what would it be useful for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $u\ne 0\in L^2$ supported on $[-r,r]$ then its Fourier transform $$\hat{u}(z)=\int_\Bbb{R} u(t)e^{-i z x}dx$$ is entire and $u(z)=O(e^{r|\Im(z)|})$ as $|z|\to \infty$.

$\hat{u}(z^2)$ is $L^2(\Bbb{R})$ and entire but it isn't $O(e^{R|\Im(z)|})$ for any $R$, whence $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\hat{u}(z^2))$ is $L^2$ but not compactly supported.

Comment: Thanks @reuns.  I just wondered how compact supports behave under simple compositions.